# Rendering nested SVG elements in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

In a React application, when a SVG root element in a Component contains a hierarchy of other nested SVG components, most of which are static background graphics that never change, what is the best way of frequently rendering the most deeply nested SVG element (based on a React state) without rendering the entire enclosing SVG tree?

For example, in this React component, there are `svg` elements which are either static (marked with `className='svg-static-element'` or which almost never update (the `svg` group that updates when `config` changes), so I can render them inline or memoize them.

But what is the way to handle a `svg` component nested deep inside this hierarchy which needs to update very often (whenver `data` changes, in this example)? I can't memoize the entire tree.

```js
const RES = 700
const SVG_VIEWBOX = `${-(RES/2)} ${-(RES/2)} ${RES} ${RES}`
const RADIUS = 10

// "config" is almost never updated
// "data" is updated many times per second
export default function UI({ data, config }) {
  return (
    <div className='root-svg'>
      <svg viewBox={SVG_VIEWBOX} preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet' className='fade-in'>
        <g className='svg-static-element' />
        <circle className='svg-static-element' cx='0' cy='0' r={RADIUS * 1.1} />
        <g className='svg-static-element' textAnchor='middle' fontSize='12em'>
          {config.someProperty.map((l, index) =>
           <text
            x='0'
            y={-RADIUS}
            dy='0.25em'
            transform={`rotate(${config.direction * index * config.degrees})`}
            className={'item-' + index}
            >{l}</text>)}
        </g>
        <g className='svg-dynamic-element'>
          {/* SVG elements that depend on the "data" prop */}
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of what isn't working?

Comment: The question didn't mention anything not working. I was looking for design ideas and best practices. But I've edited it with some simplified example code. Thanks.

Comment: Just convert `<g>` with `svg-dynamic-element` to a separate component and pass `data` to it. The `UI` component will not be updated each time the `data` changed, only the child component inside

Comment: Sorry to tax your patience but I don't get it. The `UI` component gets its `data` and `config` props from its parent component. If I extract the nested dynamic element to a separate component I can pass it `data` of course, but from where? From the `UI` component itself ? The `UI` component is rendered by its parent component which calculates both `data` and `config`, and this doesn't avoid rendering the entire static `svg` tree at each render pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
const ConfigComponent = ({config}) => (
  <>
    <g className='svg-static-element' />
    <circle className='svg-static-element' cx='0' cy='0' r={RADIUS * 1.1} />
    <g className='svg-static-element' textAnchor='middle' fontSize='12em'>
      {config.someProperty.map((l, index) =>
        <text
            x='0'
            y={-RADIUS}
            dy='0.25em'
            transform={`rotate(${config.direction * index * config.degrees})`}
            className={'item-' + index}
            >{l}</text>
      )}
    </g>
  </>
);

const DataComponent = ({data}) => (
  <g className='svg-dynamic-element'>
    {/* SVG elements that depend on the "data" prop */}
  </g>
);

const UI = ({data, config}) => (
  <div className='root-svg'>
    <svg viewBox={SVG_VIEWBOX} preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet' className='fade-in'>
       <ConfigComponent config={config} />
       <DataComponent data={data} />
    </svg>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Here's what I don't get: `UI` gets its `data` prop from a parent component. That parent parent component will re-render itself and all its children if its `data` state changes. So even if `config` doesn't change, React will still render the `OuterComponent` when the parent of `UI` is updated. Or am I wrong? BTW I am getting closer to another solution by using `forwardRef`, I'll post it here if it works, but I'm still very much interesting in understanding your approach to this.

Comment: As long as I know, rendering children does not imply rendering parent components in React - if you pass `config` only to the outer component, it will not re-render when `data` is changed. You can check it with adding console logs to both components

Comment: I have followed your example to the letter (I believe), and the `Outer Component` still re-renders on every change to the `data` state. I can confirm this both with `console.log` inside `Outer Component` and with the bounding box from DevTools. The only difference is that I now get another bounding box around `Inner Component`, but they both render at the exact same high frequency corresponding to the `data` updates.

Comment: Which seems logical since the component which is rendering `UI` and passes it its `data` and `config` state re-renders any time any of these change, even if I remove all references to the `Outer` and `Inner` components and just return an empty `div`.

Comment: @Cirrocumulus see my edited answer - a similar solution without nesting

Comment: Thanks. I marked the answer as accepted because it has useful information. However, after much reading, in this case I think a vanilla JS implemention by using a React DOM reference (`useRef` or `forwardRef`) is better. [This article](https://www.streaver.com/blog/posts/react-animations-how-a-simple-component-can-affect-your-performance) seems to confirm that updating and re-rendering complex animations using React states is not optimal.